# MongoDB - Autocomplete - Get all words starting with X

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection (users) with the following structure:

```
{
   propA: {
        words: ["i", "have", "an","important", "question"]
   }
}
```

I want to get autocomplete options from the db for some input in my website.
So first, i think that i need to create an index for propA.words.
Maybe something like this(?):

```
db.users.createIndex({ "propA.words" : 1 })
```

Second, how can i query this index to get all the words starting with X?
For example, for the string "i", the query will retrieve ["i", "important"].

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
This is the collection:

```
{
    propA: {
        words: ["aa","bb","cc","dd"]
    }
}
{
    propA: {
        words: ["ab"]
    }
}
{
    propA: {
        words: []
    } 
}
{
    propB: []
}
```

Now, i want a query to get all the words that starts with "a".
The query should return ["aa","ab"] on the above collection.
I want the query to use only the index so the search will be efficient.

Comment: You can use regex search, using [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/index.html).

Comment: But after creating the index,i just query users collection and it automatically will use the index?

Comment: Yes,  when you use that field as part of the query filter the index will be used (depends upon your query filter fields and also other indexes). But, with regex queries to use the index effectively you have to use the _starts with_ criteria - `{ name: { $regex: '^jac' } }`. See [$regex and index usage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/index.html#index-use).

Comment: But i have a list of strings, not a string property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this aggregation, which iterates over the `words` array and matches the regex search string.

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  { 
    $addFields: { 
        matches: { 
            $filter: { 
                input: "$propA.words", 
                as: "w",
                cond: {
                    $regexMatch: { input: "$$w" , regex: "^i"  } 
                }
            } 
        } 
    } 
  }
] )
```

The output:

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "propA" : {
                "words" : [
                        "i",
                        "have",
                        "an",
                        "important",
                        "question"
                ]
        },
        "matches" : [
                "i",
                "important"
        ]
}
```

---

**[ EDIT ADD ]**

> Now, i want a query to get all the words that starts with "a". The
>   query should return ["aa","ab"] on the above collection. I want the
>   query to use only the index so the search will be efficient.

The **aggregation**:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  { 
      $match: { "propA.words": { $regex: "^a" } } 
  },
  { 
      $unwind: "$propA.words" 
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: null, 
          matchedWords: { 
              $addToSet: { 
                  $cond: [ { $regexMatch: { input: "$propA.words", regex: "^a"  } }, 
                            "$propA.words",  
                            "$DUMMY" ] 
              } 
          } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $project: { _id: 0 } 
  }
] )
```

The **result**:

```
{ "matchedWords" : [ "ab", "aa" ] }
```

**Index** usage:

The index is created on the collection as follows:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "propA.words": 1 } )
```

You can *verify* the index usage on the aggregation's `$match` stage by applying the `explain` and generating a *query plan*. For example:

```
db.collection.explain("executionStats").aggregate( [ ... ] )
```

Comment: But it will use only the index of the words prop? because the aggregation is on the users collection

Comment: Can you explain? i tried to run this query in mongoshell and it outputs the whole collection.

Comment: Yes, that correct. It outputs the whole collection. What is the expected output? Suppose you have 3 documents in the collection with some data, what would be the output? What is it you are expecting as output. Please give an example, with three documents and the expected output.

Comment: Thanks it works ! :) What is the meaning of "$DUMMY" ?

Comment: The `$cond` requires a third parameter. I have to put something there (a dummy value means removing it later), so a dummy variable (it doesn't _add_ anything to the data). Otherwise, making the code differently, I think. I felt thats the best way, without adding too many stages to the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

yes you make an index on the field, which is an array.  then use regex query - the symbol ^ for 'starts with'...   an index on an array field can create a big load... but your query being a 'start-with' is an efficient design....

Comment: But i have a list of strings, not a string property