# How to find if any field includes a specific value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of objects and I would like to find if there is any field in those objects that includes a specific value.

The query I did is for searching in a specific field:

```
ExampleModel.find({
  $expr: {
    $in: ['myString', "$names"]
  }
})
```

I would like to search if any field includes 'myString' and I did not find any answer in google.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: You can try aggregation array operator `$filter` along with `$regexMatch`. If you are using MongoDB v4.4, then  you can use the `$function`.

Comment: Been trying to search for $filter and $regexMatch and I've found that I need to define a specific field for it. any chane you can help me with how to do it so I can search the value on all fields ?

Comment: See this posts answer: [MongoDB - Autocomplete - Get all words starting with X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60727003/mongodb-autocomplete-get-all-words-starting-with-x)

Comment: Also see [Aggregation Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/).

Answer (score 1):

Use `$objectToArray` to transpose the document, they you can filter on `v` field:

```
db.ExampleModel.aggregate([
   { $addFields: { data: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } } },
   { $match: { "data.v": "myString" } },
   { $unset: "data" }
])
```

Note, this does not work for embedded objects, for the first level on fields it should be fine.